# Замена повторяющихся символов

Tags: php

У меня существует переменная в которой огромный текст. Допустим отрывок из текста: *gjhlw!asghFDXCCCCCCCCsdgUYYTTTTTTTEdFF*

Как заменить повторяющиеся символы примерно в такой вид: C(8)
, тоесть шаблон такой: символ(кол-во повторений)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$text="aaaaaa bbbbbbb cccc";
$re="/(.)\\1+/";
echo preg_replace_callback($re, "clb", $text);
function clb ($s) {
    return $s[1]."(".strlen($s[0]).")";
};
//  a(6) b(7) c(4)
```